# I have a query related to Computer Architecture

Tags: cpu-architecture

20% of the total instructions in an application are multiplies. A new processor cuts the CPI for
multiplies from 10 to 5 but increases the cycle time by 20%. All other instructions take 1 cycle
each to process.
What is the speedup of the new processor compared to the old one?

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate normal CPI:

```
CPI = (SIGMA(Intruction_Count*Instruction_Precentage)/Total_Instructions)*Cycle_Length
```

Calculating the old cpi we get:

```
CPI_OLD= ( 10*0.2 + 1*0.8 ) * 1 = 2.8
```

Adjusting for the new changes we get:

```
CPI_NEW = (5*0.2 + 1*0.8) * 1.2 = 2.16

Speedup = CPI_NEW/CPI_OLD = 1.3
```

Comment: Please tell me how you calculated the CPI. 
I am unable to understand the factor that you multiplied. for example: (5*0.2 + 1*0.8) * 1.2 . What is 1.2 in this scenerio?

Comment: I changed the answer, tell me if you understood now.

Comment: In my case, cycle length is 1. But in CPI_NEW, you took it as 1.2. That is not understandable.

Comment: It's because cycle_old/cycle_new=1.2 . Try using the equation to solve it for yourself.

Comment: I got it. It was helpful. Thanks